# Regex containing variable when regex comparison

Tags: regex, bash

I want to write a bash script that takes an input string and if it doesn't contain a particular tag in the beginning, add the tag to the beginning. The following is the script I wrote

```
#! /bin/bash

message=$1

tag="hello"

filter="^$tag.*"

if [[ ! $message =~ $filter ]]; then
   message="$tag $message"
fi

echo $message
```

This works well as long as the tag doesn't contain a  regular expression specific keyword.

For example if the tag was set to `[hello]` the filter doesn't work since the square bracket is a keyword.

How to change the `filter` so that it ignores any keywords containing in the `tag`?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shell patterns instead of regular expressions and [quote them to avoid interpretation of meta characters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b):

```
if [[ $message != "$tag"* ]]; then
    message="$tag $message"
fi
```